# Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt .....Singleton instance not initialized yet - but workin in local VM

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

Starting our Server, we always get an exception starting with:

```
WARN  [localhost-startStop-5] [TenantIgnoreXmlWebApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultDataToWsConverterList': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsPageDataToWsConverter' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPageDataToWsConverter' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsDataMapper' while setting bean property 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCMSDataMapper' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton instance not initialized yet
```

This only happens on our Testsystem, but everything is fine in the local VM. The beans mentioned are part of hybris (I checked them, but they seem fine and I didn't touch anything and like I said it's working local) and the AddOn should be installed properly

```
     <antcall target="addoninstall">
            <param name="addonnames" value="cmsoccaddon"/>
            <param name="addonStorefront.ycommercewebservices" value="ycommercewebservices"/>
        </antcall>
```

Stacktrace:

```
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.392 | INFO  [localhost-startStop-4] [PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping] Mapped URL path [/api-docs] onto method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json> springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
    INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.392 | WARN  [localhost-startStop-5] [TenantIgnoreXmlWebApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultDataToWsConverterList': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsPageDataToWsConverter' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPageDataToWsConverter' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsDataMapper' while setting bean property 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCMSDataMapper' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton instance not initialized yet
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.392 | INFO  [localhost-startStop-5] [TenantAwareEhCacheManagerFactoryBean] Shutting down EhCache CacheManager 'wsCache_master'
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.492 | ERROR [localhost-startStop-5] [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.492 | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultDataToWsConverterList': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsPageDataToWsConverter' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPageDataToWsConverter' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsDataMapper' while setting bean property 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCMSDataMapper' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton instance not initialized yet
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.492 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:314) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.492 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.492 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:159) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1674) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:828) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401) ~[spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292) [spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:226) [coreserver.jar:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:199) [coreserver.jar:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) [spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.493 |     at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:95) [coreserver.jar:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.494 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.494 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.494 |     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.494 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.494 |     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402) [catalina.jar:8.5.51]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.494 |     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.494 |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.494 |     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPageDataToWsConverter' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsDataMapper' while setting bean property 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCMSDataMapper' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton instance not initialized yet
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:314) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1674) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.495 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     ... 29 more
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCMSDataMapper' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton instance not initialized yet
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1674) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.496 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     ... 29 more
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton instance not initialized yet
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.getSingletonInstance(AbstractFactoryBean.java:188) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.access$200(AbstractFactoryBean.java:63) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean$EarlySingletonInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractFactoryBean.java:275) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy272.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at de.hybris.platform.cmsoccaddon.mapping.DefaultCMSDataMapper.configure(DefaultCMSDataMapper.java:43) ~[cmsoccaddonserver.jar:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.ConfigurableMapper.init(ConfigurableMapper.java:119) ~[orika-core-1.5.2.jar:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at de.hybris.platform.webservicescommons.mapping.impl.DefaultDataMapper.setApplicationContext(DefaultDataMapper.java:74) ~[webservicescommonsserver.jar:?]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:414) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1763) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.497 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.498 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.498 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.498 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.498 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1674) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:303) ~[spring-beans-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar:5.1.13.RELEASE]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 |     ... 29 more
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 | Mai 26, 2020 7:17:20 NACHM. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 | SCHWERWIEGEND: Fehler beim Senden der 'Context Initialized' Benachrichtigung an den Listener aus der Klasse [de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener]
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.499 | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultDataToWsConverterList': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsPageDataToWsConverter' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultPageDataToWsConverter' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cmsDataMapper' while setting bean property 'mapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultCMSDataMapper' defined in class path resource [cmsoccaddon/web/spring/cmsoccaddon-web-spring.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton instance not initialized yet
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:314)
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:399)
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:159)
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1674)
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1426)
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2020/05/26 19:17:20.500 |     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
```

After that the server keeps booting and the most things seem to work, but not everthing, like caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On got installed properly, the above exception comes when having the issue with addon installation.

Please Verify on the test server, your addon is installed properly on the given storefront.

to verify the addon please this property is injected in your addon or not.

```
XXXstorefront.additionalWebSpringConfigs.XXXsocialwebaddon=classpath\:/XXXsocialwebaddon/web/spring/XXXsocialwebaddon-web-spring.xml
```

XXXstorefront.wro4jconfigscan.XXXsocialwebaddon=true

Later if you don't want to run ant target to install addon please add this property to local.properties or specific to storefront project.properties.

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed not installed properly on the server (but in local vm). ycommercewebservices was the wrong value.